# sas array not updating value

Tags: arrays, sas

This sas code is supposed to update the raf with each iteration and then the new raf value is multiplied to create an updated est_bign. But the raf value is not updated. I have put statements I just removed them so save space.

```
This is how it is now:
    est_bign_r  raf
    207640.2    1.002402
    207640.2    1.002402

   This is how is should be:
    207640.17   1.0024
    219236.92   0.94938

Here is the full code:
    data &dsource..initial_raf 
     hold_output3_orig ;
 set &dsource..begin_raf;
 by tow cgroup_raf cell_raf;
 i_rake = 1;    /* First N_RAKE loop */
 array comp_int[0:2] $1 comp_int_0-comp_int_2;
 array post_naf_wgt[0:&repnum] 8 post_naf_wgt0-post_naf_wgt&repnum;   /* rep_cnt */
 array estbignr[0:&repnum] 8 estbignr0-estbignr&repnum;
 array bign_r_rep[0:&repnum] 8 bign_r_0-bign_r_&repnum;
 array raf_factors[&r_start:&n_ratio,0:&repnum] 8;
 length check_raf $3 count_r 8;
 retain estbignr0-estbignr&repnum count_r 0;
 if first.cell_raf then 
 do;
  call missing(of estbignr0-estbignr&repnum);
  count_r = 0;
 end;
 if (elig_hu eq '1') then 
 do;
  if (comp_int[tow] eq '1') then    /* interview */
  do;
   do rep_cnt = 0 to &repnum;
    %if (&raf_val eq &r_start) %then
    %do;
     estbignr[rep_cnt] + (post_naf_wgt[rep_cnt] * 1 * z_r * elig_r);
    %end;
    %else %do;
     %let raf_neg = %eval(&raf_val-1);
     estbignr[rep_cnt] + (post_naf_wgt[rep_cnt] * 
                          raf_factors[&raf_neg,rep_cnt] * z_r * elig_r);
    %end;
   end;
   count_r + elig_r; 
  end;
 end;
 if (last.cell_raf) then 
 do;
  r = &raf_val;   /* R value (1 to N_RATIO) */
                  /* calculate initial RAF value */
  do rep_val = 0 to &repnum;
   if (estbignr[rep_val] lt 0) then estbignr[rep_val] = 0;
   if (estbignr[rep_val] eq 0) then raf=42;
   else raf = bign_r_rep[rep_val] / estbignr[rep_val];
/*    ?? Correct version 
   raf = bign_r / estbignr[rep_val];
   collapse_raf = '1';        /* flag for before collapsing */
   est_bign_r = estbignr[rep_val];
   bign_r = bign_r_rep[rep_val];
   if (raf lt 0.5) or (raf gt 2) or (count_r lt 25) 
     then check_raf = "bad";
     else check_raf = "ok";
   if (rep_val eq 0) then output &dsource..initial_raf;
   output hold_output3_orig;
  end;
 end;
run;
```

Comment: I assume you are inside a macro here and the macro `%IF/%THEN/%ELSE` block is OK inside the Data Step.  The Data step is not expecting `&REF_NEG` to update during its run time, correct?

Comment: Yes the array is inside a macro. And yes &ref_neg doesn't update during run time. Its set to  %let raf_neg = %eval(&raf_val-1); %do  there are two loops rake_loop = 2 %to &n_rake;  
  %do raf_val = &r_start %to &n_ratio;, 2-8 is the outer and 1-8 is the inner loop.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me that is wrong from what you provided.  As it is, we cannot replicate the issue with the information you provide.  Can you edit to give us a working example that shows your issue?  Otherwise will have to vote to close for being unclear.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should at minimum put some `put`s in the code to see if it gets into the particular if blocks that you expect it to.

Comment: My suspicion is that `%if (&raf_val eq &r_start) %then` is the problem - is this correct to be `%if` and not `if`?  Anyway, I don't see where `raf` is updated in that code.  I think we'd definitely need to know what those macro variables should be, as well.

Comment: r_start = 1 and raf_val iterates from 2 to 8.

Comment: If macro variable RAF_VAL in some larger macro loop then aren't you just overwriting the same dataset multiple times?  Why not just do only the last iteration and skip the others?